# What kind of cable does a function generator use?

Tags: connector, cables, function-generator

I picked up an [Agilent 33120A function generator](http://www.home.agilent.com/agilent/product.jspx?pn=33120A&cc=US&lc=eng) used (yay!) and I need to buy the cable that attaches the output to the circuit. Problem is, I'm not sure what kind of cable it is.

So, I guess I have two questions:

1. Does anyone know the name for this type of connector/cable?
2. Once I know the name, I'll probably try to buy it on e-bay since I'm a student and kind of strapped for cash. Is that OK, or will a cheap cable be a problem?

Comment: The outputs are BNC connectors. And the output impedance is 50 Ohms, so you can use any cable with 50 Ohm characteristic impedance. Which answers your question. However, I'm going to vote to close the question as "too localized" since its so specific to a single specific instrument.

Comment: It's not a great question, but it's hardly "localized" or specific to a single instrument, as BNC output connectors are just short of universal on instruments built for a frequency range where they are appropriate.  Matching characteristic impedance may or may not be important depending on the application, cable length, frequency, connected circuit, and generator settings.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, It is specific to one instrument, since OP asked, "what connects to an Agilent 33120A?" If he used a picture and specified a frequency range without naming a particular model instrument, I'd agree with you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function generator has a [BNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_connector) output. There are a lot of pieces of test equipment that use this connector, including oscopes. You can find many different types of BNC cables. You can get ones with probes, clips, bare wires, or BNC to BNC. You can even get BNC spliters if you want to split your signal to multiple places. What one you get (and the quality, used or new) depends on what you are wanting to use the function generator for.